# Adding more text to a cell in table in itext

Tags: java, itext, barcode

I am trying to add some text with a bar code in a table cell using itext as per the following code but it does not show in the pdf file. i tried adding chunks and paragraph. Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
Barcode128 barcode = new Barcode128();
//barcode.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN8);
barcode.setCode(code);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(barcode.createImageWithBarcode(writer.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.GRAY), true);

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello World"); 
cell.addElement(paragraph);

cell.setPadding(10);
```

Comment: doesn't it work when you add the barcode not in the constructor of the `cell`, but via a `cell.addElement()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably confused by *text* vs. *composite* mode.

When using the `PdfPCell(Image)` constructor, you create a cell in *text* mode. Any subsequent call to `addElement(Element)` will then switch the cell to *composite* mode, removing all content previously entered in the constructor.

You'll have to change your code that way:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

Barcode128 barcode = new Barcode128();
barcode.setCode(code);
Image barcodeImage = barcode.createImageWithBarcode(writer.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.GRAY);
cell.addElement(barcodeImage);

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello World"); 
cell.addElement(paragraph);
```