# Paragraph leading inside table cell

Tags: java, itext

I have a table with cells set up like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(content,font); 
p.setLeading(30); 
PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(p);
```

My problem is that the paragraph leading is ignored. Can someone please tell me how to set the paragraph leading when inside a table cell? It works perfectly when not inside a cell.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding more text to a cell in table in itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325408/adding-more-text-to-a-cell-in-table-in-itext)

Comment: @AlexisPigeon i don't think it's a duplicate, the problem here is the leading is not visible.

Comment: The question by itself is not a duplicate, but the root cause of the issue (text vs. composite mode), and the way to solve it, is similar. Note that I'm not voting to delete the question, just close it, so that no more answers than yours (which is 100% correct) is added.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Sorry, I thought it was for deletion :)

Comment: BTW, feel free to mark your answer as the accepted one, that's quite an [accepted thing to do on SO](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), in case you didn't know. You'll have to wait for 48 hours though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google for the difference between "text mode" and "composite mode". 
You are using "text mode": the leading of the cell is taken into 
account; the leading of the paragraph is ignored. 
If you use "composite mode", it's the other way round.

Try:

```
PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(); 
c.addElement(p);
```